# What is the solution to the puzzle called "Power Grid"?

Tags: puzzle-agent-2

In Puzzle Agent 2, what is the solution to the puzzle called "Power Grid"?

This is what I have tried and I cannot see my mistake:

[image]

Comment: I just loaded a video and watched the intro (where the requirements are listed). It says that the generators get split evenly if both outlets are used, so the fact that you can't choose to split the middle one 40/10 to power the second lamp is your first problem.

Comment: I would also note that the generators are the things at the back, not the front, in case that's what's tripping you up

Comment: Yes, I mixed front and back. Make it an answer and I will accept it. My bad.

Comment: It's okay, you should answer it with a screenshot of the correct answer and self-explain :P

Comment: Okay. It is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Gwen explained in the comments:

> [T]he generators are the things at the back, not the front

Moreover, all cables have to be used: you cannot use one cable for the 10 units of the generator on the left, you would only get 5 units of power.

[image: The answer]